# Replace UIViews

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I'm a newbie in iOS.
I have 5 views, one mainview and the others are like thumbnails. How can I replace view.

For example, if mainview(view1) has picture 1, view2 has picture 2, view3 has picture 3 etc.

How can I replace picture 1 with picture 2 so that View2 come in to the mainview?

Could some one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this could be done esily like this
View_1 is the first view
View_2 is the second view
containerView is the main super view for View_1
View_1 is the currently visible view

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"doTheFlipping" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myTransitionDidStop:finished:context:)];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:containerView cache:YES];

    [View_1 removeFromSuperview];
    [containerView addSubview:View_2];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will create a flip view for view 1 to view 2

Comment: For example : View_1 is class A and View_2 is Class B.

I dunot get it what you meant by containerView..

P.S: all the 5 UIViews are in one controller.

Comment: containerView = controller.view

Answer (score 1):

you not use separate views for this. see this page and download sample code from here to see detail. this is pageControl

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: First of all thanks for your Answer..

but actually they are Graphs so each views has connected with different classes(which generates coordination points to draw a graph)..

all the 5 graphs in one controller.
now I 've 4 graphs in small UIview format and one graph in a big format(half of iPhone Screen)..

Sorry for this inconvenient.

could you please help me?