# iOS: How to Group UI Items to make transitions in the same View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I'm starting a new project in iOS and i don't know how to group the UI Elements to hide/add effects/etc and i want to make some transitions between a group of elements to show others elements, idk if its make sense but for example:

In HTML when i want to group some element i make a div element with id/class

```
<div id="someId" class="someClass"> (elements) </div>
```

and when i want to do something with it in JQuery:

```
$("#someId").hide();
```

So, i don't know how to do this in XCode or in the Code, i did it tons of times in HTML/JS, but i don't know mucho of iOS.

As data: I have a dynamic background in the view (it's because i don't want to make this function in another UIView), 2 UITextField, 3 Custom UIButton and an UIImageView (background for the text's), i'm using StoryBoards.

**Image Example:**
[image]

I have 
PS: I'm new in iOS dev so i don't much about how to make things work ):

PS2: Sorry for my english i'm from Chile and i'm working in it.

Comment: " As data: I have a dynamic background in the view (it's because i don't want to make this function in another UIView)" ... You mean another UIViewController or UiView itself..?

Comment: @KumarKl another UIViewController, i don't want to add another View Controller to the Storyboard

Comment: Any problem with my answer , ? feel free to ask

Comment: @KumarKl no bro ! THANKS! it works !! it take me some time to create the two views and make it work, but thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some suggestions , Add 3 UIViews to your View Controller , one is basically for your "dynamic background " as per your requirement .
you just create the elements to the `UIVIEW1` and `UIVIEW2` as per requirement .

In the "`ViewDidLoad`" just hide the `UIView2` using "" `myview2.Hidden=YES` "" .
Later you can disable it whenever you hit "create your Account" button , just add the event handlers to hide `myView1` and enable `myView2`.

[image]

if you still not getting the way here , Just refer this link . It may help you.

> [Replace UIViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704026/replace-uiviews)

Hope it helps .